# Likes feature in Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, url, django-templates

I'm trying to implement a Like feature for my web app. Here is the code:

Model:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes')
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    total_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

View:

```
def like(request):
    vars = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.user
        slug = request.POST.get('slug', None)
        doctor = get_object_or_404(Doctor, slug=slug)

        liked, created = Like.objects.create(Doctor=doctor)

        try:
            user_liked = Like.objects.get(Doctor=doctor, user=user)
        except:
            user_liked = None

        if user_liked:
            user_liked.total_likes -= 1
            liked.user.remove(request.user)
            user_liked.save()
        else:
            liked.user.add(request.user)
            liked.total_likes += 1
            liked.save()


    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(vars),
                mimetype='application/javascript')
```

URL:

```
url(r'^like/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.like, name='like'),
```

Template:

```
<input type="button" id="like" name="{{doctor_slug}}" value="Like" />

<script>
$('#like').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "{% url like %}",
               data: {'slug': $(this).attr('name'), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},
               dataType: "text",
               success: function(response) {
                      alert('You liked this')
                },
                error: function(rs, e) {
                       alert(rs.responseText);
                }
          }); 
    })
</script>
```

When I open my template page, I get the error `NoReverseMatch at /docprofile/1/
'url' requires a non-empty first argument. The syntax changed in Django 1.5, see the docs.` I looked at the docs but couldn't find anything that I could use here. The problem seems to be in the template at `"url: "{% url like %}","`. This is inside Ajax.

Comment: You need to tell django which id you want to like for the url reverse translation to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you should see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls). You need to pass the path to the view function or the name of the url to the url template tag as a string.

```
<script>
$('#like').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "{% url 'like' %}",
               data: {'slug': $(this).attr('name'), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},
               dataType: "text",
               success: function(response) {
                      alert('You liked this')
                },
                error: function(rs, e) {
                       alert(rs.responseText);
                }
          }); 
    })
</script>
```